# which process puts in waiting queue

Tags: operating-system, queue, semaphore

Assume we are using semaphores for providing mutual exclusion and one process is executing in critical section. Then another process comes to use the critical region, would it be put into the waiting queue?

I have a doubt that which process puts this process in the waiting queue?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

In a typical operating system this is handled by the kernel and not a process. The kernel keeps track of what critical regions exist and which processes are occupying them. Also in a typical operating system the scheduler is also part of the kernel so it is the scheduler that will put the process in a waiting state (or to be more precise more likely a blocking state).

Answer (score 1):

When a thread/process/task requests a mutual exclusion object, it makes a *system call* to the kernel where mutual exclusion objects are handled. If this object is not available at the moment, then the kernel puts this thread/process/task in the waiting/blocked queue and elects another one.